# Open response on new window

Tags: django

In Django, how can I get the response to be opened in a new window from the view?

if i do this, this will open the mynewpage.html in the original window

```
return HttpResponse('mynewpage')
```

I want to open mynewpage.html in a new window , separate from the originial.

Answer (score 7):

Your server has no concept of windows - it just sends back files to the browser. [You need to do this via javascript:](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm)

```
window.open('url to open','window name','attribute1,attribute2')
```

So you can either create a custom view and template whose job is to open a new window with a specified link, then return the main window to the page it was previously at, or simply open the url you want from the original window without contacting the server

Comment: Javascript in django ?  how do it ?